# .net core 3.1 app wont run on browser via docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, .net-core-3.1

i created 2 default projects ( WEB API ) from visual studio , one with .net core 2.1 and the other with .net core 3.1! generated dockerfiles for both using visual studio !

dockerfile for both is like bellow

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build 
your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1 AS base // version 3.1 for my other project
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1 AS build // version 3.1 for my other project
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication2.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore "./WebApplication2.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication2.dll"]
```

and this is my launchSetting

```
       "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:80"
```

these are the exact command i use to build and run my dockerfile

```
  docker build -t mohammadjavani/app21 .
  docker run -p 8080:80 mohammadjavani/app21

  docker build -t mohammadjavani/app31 .
  docker run -p 8080:80 mohammadjavani/app31
```

after i run my app21 i could view my app in my brower in localhost:80
but as mohammadjavani/app31 after i stopped app21 container and run app31 i couldnt view my app in brower !

dockerfiles are generated in visual studio and commands i used are the exact same for both project
what could be wrong with my .net core 3.1 dockerfile project ??

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try using the environment variable `ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+:443;http://+:80"`

```
docker run -p 8080:80 mohammadjavani/app31 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+:443;http://+:80"
```